# how to bind "name attribute" in angular js loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can i add name attribute to the input tag using angular.js, 
Question field can be add with just a click, similarly option input can also added, but problem is that when i try to add new option, i got blank **name attribute** 
like this : `name="qz_options[]"` , but i want to bind some data here like this `name="qz_options[{{formData.qz_question[$index + 1]}}]"`, how can i add more input field (option named input text field), please help

```html
<fieldset ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label>Enter Your Contest Question</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" name="qz_question[]" class="form-control"
                       ng-model="formData.qz_question[$index + 1]" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button type="button" name="remove" ng-model="row.remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" ng-click="removeRow(row)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
            </div>
            <fieldset ng-repeat="option in options" class="col-12 mt-3 bg-white p-3">
                <label>Options</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" name="qz_options[{{formData.qz_question[$index + 1]}}]" class="form-control"  />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <button type="button" name="remove" ng-model="option.remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="removeOptionRow(row)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>

                        <button type="button" name="add_more_option" ng-model="option.options"  ng-click="addOpp()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" >
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-3"><hr></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" name="add_more" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addRow()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Question</button>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save Contest" />
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('dynamicApp', []);

app.controller('dynamicController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.success = false;
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.rows = [{name: 'qz_question[]', name: 'remove'}];

    //options
    $scope.options = [{name: 'qz_options[{{formData.qz_question[$index + 1]}}]', name: 'remove'}];

    $scope.addRow = function(){
        var id = $scope.rows.length + 1;
        $scope.rows.push({'id':'dynamic'+id});
    };
    $scope.removeRow = function(row){
        var index = $scope.rows.indexOf(row);
        $scope.rows.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.addOpp = function(){
        var id = $scope.options.length + 1;
        $scope.options.push({'id':'dynamic'+id});
    };
    $scope.removeOptionRow = function(row){
        var index = $scope.options.indexOf(row);
        $scope.options.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.submitForm = function(){

        alert("working");
       // $http.get('api/url-api').then(successCallback, errorCallback);

        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"insert.php",
            data:$scope.formData
        }).then(
            function(data)
            {
              //  alert(JSON.parse(data));
                alert(JSON.stringify(data,null, 4));

                if(data.error != '')
            {
                $scope.success = false;
                $scope.error = true;
                $scope.errorMessage = data.error;
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.success = true;
                $scope.error = false;
                $scope.successMessage = data.message;
                $scope.formData = {};
                $scope.rows = [{name: 'programming_languages[]', name: 'remove'}];
                //$scope.fetchData();
            }
        }, function(error){
                alert(error);
            });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do

```
name=“{{qz_options[formData.qz_question[$index + 1]]}}“
```